# Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngShow', can't be found

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am new to angularjs and trying to call a function during onclick of submit button.

**My HTML Page :**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="showGraph = !showGraph" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-disabled="!model.selectedRole">SUBMIT</a>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div><! end of previous div -->

<div class="col-sm-6"> <!-- new div -->
            <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#F8F8FF; text-decoration:none; color:black"><b>Chart</b></div>
                <div class="panel-body" ng-change="HeadCount()" ng-show="showGraph">

          <plot class="barchart" height="300" width="400" yaxis-label-text="'No. of Students'"
                          xaxis-label-text="'standards'" ymin="0" ymax="100" xodomain="ordinals" >
                        <bar-group  type="'grouped'" arrangement="'vertical'" style="opacity:100;">
                            <bars  data="available_students" position-function="'/0'" value-function="'/1'"
                                  fill="'red'"></bars>
                            <bars data="maximum_students" position-function="'/0'" value-function="'/1'" fill="'blue'" ></bars>
                        </bar-group>

                    </plot>
                </div>

          </div>
           </div> <!-- end of new div -->
```

Here I am using `ng-click="showGraph = !showGraph"` to call my showGraph in my controller.

**My controller Page**

```
$scope.showGraph = false;

 $scope.HeadCount = function(){

            var json_response =  {

                      "data": [
                        {
                          "standard": "Ist",
                          "max_students": 20,
                          "available_students": 8
                        },
                        {
                          "standard": "IInd",
                          "max_students": 15,
                          "available_students": 10
                        },
                        {
                          "standard": "IIIrd",
                          "max_students": 50,
                          "available_students": 22
                        }
                      ]
                    } 
     $scope.available_students = [ ['Ist', 8,], ['IInd', 10], ['IIIrd', 22]];
     $scope.maximum_students = [['Ist', 15], ['IInd',15], ['IIIrd', 50]];
     $scope.ordinals = ['Ist', 'IInd', 'IIIrd'];
     console.log($scope.ordinals.length);
     $cookieStore.put('xaxisLength',$scope.ordinals.length);

    }
```

I need to show the chart by calling `HeadCount()`function from controller after clicking on submit button.

But I am getting below error and when i click on submit button form is getting refreshed.

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngShow', can't be found!
```

Can anyone please help me where i need to make changes.

Comment: ngChange is only used with form elements not with div.

Answer (score 0):

ng-change directive requires a ng-model directive. Add a ng-model to this line:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-change="HeadCount()" ng-show="showGraph">
```

Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$scope.showGraph` and graph rendering code on click of a.

Get ride of `ng-change` from below div.

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="showGraph">
```

HTML: add `renderGraph` to `ng-click`.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="renderGraph()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-disabled="!model.selectedRole">SUBMIT</a>
```

JS:
Set the `$scope.showGraph` here.

```
  $scope.renderGraph = function(){
    $scope.showGraph = !$scope.showGraph;
    if($scope.showGraph) {
        var json_response =  {
          "data": [
            {
              "standard": "Ist",
              "max_students": 20,
              "available_students": 8
            },
            {
              "standard": "IInd",
              "max_students": 15,
              "available_students": 10
            },
            {
              "standard": "IIIrd",
              "max_students": 50,
              "available_students": 22
            }
          ]
        };
         $scope.available_students = [ ['Ist', 8,], ['IInd', 10], ['IIIrd', 22]];
         $scope.maximum_students = [['Ist', 15], ['IInd',15], ['IIIrd', 50]];
         $scope.ordinals = ['Ist', 'IInd', 'IIIrd'];
         console.log($scope.ordinals.length);
         $cookieStore.put('xaxisLength',$scope.ordinals.length);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-change can not be called on the ng-show directive change . it will be called only when a binding element will change . So you need to put the ng-change somewhere in the input element element which has binding with it using ng-model .

In your case you need to call the HeadCount() in this line

```
<a href="#" ng-click="HeadCount(); showGraph = !showGraph" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"           ng-disabled="!model.selectedRole">SUBMIT</a>
```

I hope this will help .